# Why does my CUDA kernel crash (unspecified launch failure) with a different dataset size?

Tags: cuda

I have a kernel to calculate different elements of a matrix, based on their position (diagonal or off-diagonal). The kernel works as expected when calculating matrices of sizes:

- 14 x 14 (I understand this is small and does not make proper use of the GPU resources but this was purely for testing purposes to ensure results were correct)
- 118 x 118, and
- 300 x 300

However, when I am trying to calculate a matrix of size 2383 x 2383, the kernel crashes. Specifically, the error "Unspecified launch failure" is thrown on the cudaMemcpy() line to return results from device to host. From research, I understand that this error usually arises in the case of an out of bounds memory access (e.g. in an array), however, what I don't get is that it works for the three previous cases but not for the 2383 x 2383 case. The kernel code is shown below:

```
__global__ void createYBus(float *R, float *X, float *B, int numberOfBuses, int numberOfBranches, int *fromBus, int *toBus, cuComplex *y)
{
    int rowIdx = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int colIdx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int index = rowIdx*numberOfBuses + colIdx;
    if (rowIdx<numberOfBuses && colIdx<numberOfBuses)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfBranches; ++i)
        {
            if (rowIdx==fromBus[i] && colIdx==fromBus[i]) { //diagonal element
                y[index] = cuCaddf(y[index], make_cuComplex((R[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i]))), (-(X[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i])))+ (B[i]/2))));
            }
            if (rowIdx==toBus[i] && colIdx==toBus[i]) { //diagonal element
                y[index] = cuCaddf(y[index], make_cuComplex((R[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i]))), (-(X[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i])))+ (B[i]/2))));
            }
            if (rowIdx==fromBus[i] && colIdx==toBus[i]) { //off-diagonal element
                y[index] = make_cuComplex(-(R[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i]))), X[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i])));
            }
            if (rowIdx==toBus[i] && colIdx==fromBus[i]) { //off-diagonal element
                y[index] = make_cuComplex(-(R[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i]))), X[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i])));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Global memory allocations are done via calls to cudaMalloc(). The allocations made in the code are as follows:

```
cudaStat1 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_fromBus, numLines*sizeof(int));
cudaStat2 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_toBus, numLines*sizeof(int));
cudaStat3 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_R, numLines*sizeof(float));
cudaStat4 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_X, numLines*sizeof(float));
cudaStat5 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_B, numLines*sizeof(float));
cudaStat6 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_y, numberOfBuses*numberOfBuses*sizeof(cuComplex));
cudaStat7 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_Pd, numberOfBuses*sizeof(float));
cudaStat8 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_Qd, numberOfBuses*sizeof(float));
cudaStat9 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_Vmag, numberOfBuses*sizeof(float));
cudaStat10 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_theta, numberOfBuses*sizeof(float));
cudaStat11 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_Peq, numberOfBuses*sizeof(float));
cudaStat12 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_Qeq, numberOfBuses*sizeof(float));
cudaStat13 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_Peq1, numberOfBuses*sizeof(float));
cudaStat14 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_Qeq1, numberOfBuses*sizeof(float));
...
...
cudaStat15 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_powerMismatch, jacSize*sizeof(float));
cudaStat16 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_jacobian, jacSize*jacSize*sizeof(float));
cudaStat17 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_stateVector, jacSize*sizeof(float));
cudaStat18 = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_PQindex, jacSize*sizeof(int));
```

where cudaStatN are of type cudaError_t to catch errors. The last four allocations were done later on in the code and are for another kernel. However these allocations were done before the kernel in question was called.

The launch parameters are as follows:

```
dim3 dimBlock(16, 16); //number of threads 
dim3 dimGrid((numberOfBuses+15)/16, (numberOfBuses+15)/16);  //number of blocks

//launch kernel once data has been copied to GPU
createYBus<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(dev_R, dev_X, dev_B, numberOfBuses, numLines, dev_fromBus, dev_toBus, dev_y);

//copy results back to CPU
cudaStat6 = cudaMemcpy(y_bus, dev_y, numberOfBuses*numberOfBuses*sizeof(cuComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
if (cudaStat6 != cudaSuccess) {
    cout<<"Device memcpy failed"<<endl;
    cout<<cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat6)<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

I removed the timing code just to show the block and grid dimensions and error checking technique used.

I also have a host (C++ code) version of this function and I'm passing the data to both functions and then comparing results, firstly, to ensure the kernel produces correct results, and secondly in terms of execution time to compare performance. I have double checked the data for the 2383 x 2383 case (it's being read in from a text file and copied to global memory) and I'm not finding any anomalies in array accesses/indexing.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, so I tried using Nsight to find the error (I'm not too well-versed with Nsight). The summary report overview states: "There was 1 runtime API call error reported. (Please see the CUDA Runtime API Calls report for further information). In the list of runtime API calls, cudaMemcpy returns error 4 - not sure if the Thread ID (5012) is of any significance in the table - this number varies with every run. CUDA memcheck tool (in the command line) returns the following:

```
Thank you for using this program
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 4) due to "unspecified launch failure" on CUDA API call to cudaMemcpy.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
```

I know my kernel isn't the most efficient as there are many global memory accesses. Why is the kernel crashing for this larger matrix? Is there an out of bounds array access that I'm missing? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be that memory allocation size has some mismatch with parameters. Could you also share allocation calls as well ?

Comment: Are you sure your value of "int index", in your kernel, is correct ? Shouldn't it depend on the blocks' dimensions instead ?

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET I edited the post to include allocation calls. I understand that global memory is large but is it possible that I am allocating too much memory? I am not getting any errors for cudaMalloc() calls though.

Comment: @Taro I am launching a 2D grid with 2D blocks. The global thread ID is calculated in the x and y directions, then index combines the global thread ID formulae to index the full matrix in flattened form.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solved the problem. Turns out the WDDM TDR (timeout detecion recovery) was enabled and the delay was set to 2 seconds. This means that if the kernel execution time exceeds 2s, the driver will crash and recover. This is applicable to graphics and rendering (for general purpose uses of the GPU). In this case however, the TDR must either me disabled or the delay increased. By increasing the delay to 10s, the crash error "unspecified launch failure" ceased to appear and kernel execution continued as before.

The TDR delay (as well as enabling/disabling) can be done through Nsight options in the Nsight Monitor or through the Registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers) - DWORDS Tdrdelay and Tdrlevel.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, you are a hero!

Comment: This was exactly my problem, thanks a lot. I wonder why it is so hard to find this answer through Google?

Comment: This is generally applicable to all CUDA use cases - specifically MATLAB. Just fixed a problem I've had for a number of days!

Comment: I have created a DWORD registry entry for Tdrdelay. Should I create another registry entry for Tdrlevel? What should be the value of Tdrlevel?

Comment: This answer was back in 2016... Just like the guy above said, why is it so hard to find this answer! This solved my issue! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your code with the following complete example. The code compiles, runs with no error.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>

#include "cuComplex.h"

__global__ void createYBus(float *R, float *X, float *B, int numberOfBuses, int numberOfBranches, int *fromBus, int *toBus, cuComplex *y)
{
    int rowIdx = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int colIdx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int index = rowIdx*numberOfBuses + colIdx;
    if (rowIdx<numberOfBuses && colIdx<numberOfBuses)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfBranches; ++i)
        {
            if (rowIdx==fromBus[i] && colIdx==fromBus[i]) { //diagonal element
                y[index] = cuCaddf(y[index], make_cuComplex((R[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i]))), (-(X[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i])))+ (B[i]/2))));
            }
            if (rowIdx==toBus[i] && colIdx==toBus[i]) { //diagonal element
                y[index] = cuCaddf(y[index], make_cuComplex((R[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i]))), (-(X[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i])))+ (B[i]/2))));
            }
            if (rowIdx==fromBus[i] && colIdx==toBus[i]) { //off-diagonal element
                y[index] = make_cuComplex(-(R[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i]))), X[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i])));
            }
            if (rowIdx==toBus[i] && colIdx==fromBus[i]) { //off-diagonal element
                y[index] = make_cuComplex(-(R[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i]))), X[i]/((R[i]*R[i])+(X[i]*X[i])));
            }
        }
    }
}


int main ()
{
    int numLines = 32 ;
    int numberOfBuses = 2383 ;

    int* dev_fromBus, *dev_toBus;
    float *dev_R, *dev_X, *dev_B;
    cuComplex* dev_y ; 

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_fromBus, numLines*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_toBus, numLines*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_R, numLines*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_X, numLines*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_B, numLines*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_y, numberOfBuses*numberOfBuses*sizeof(cuComplex));

    dim3 dimBlock(16, 16); //number of threads 
    dim3 dimGrid((numberOfBuses+15)/16, (numberOfBuses+15)/16);  //number of blocks

    //launch kernel once data has been copied to GPU
    createYBus<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(dev_R, dev_X, dev_B, numberOfBuses, numLines, dev_fromBus, dev_toBus, dev_y);

    cuComplex* y_bus = new cuComplex[numberOfBuses*numberOfBuses] ;

    //copy results back to CPU
    cudaError_t cudaStat6 = cudaMemcpy(y_bus, dev_y, numberOfBuses*numberOfBuses*sizeof(cuComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStat6 != cudaSuccess) {
        printf ("failure : (%d) - %s\n", cudaStat6, ::cudaGetErrorString(cudaStat6)) ;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Your error seems to be somewhere else.

You want to run your code in NSIGHT debug mode with cuda mem check activated. If compiled with debug information, the tool should point out the location of your error.

**EDIT**: The problem appears to ne caused by WDDM TDR as discussed in comment.

Comment: I am curious on the reason for the downvote. I would be happy to improve the answer.

Comment: This will work just as the smaller cases work. The numLines variable comes from the number of lines in the text file in which the data is stored. The number of lines is 2896. Each column in the text file is stored as an array (fromBus, toBus, R, X, B) which are then copied to their allocated device counterparts (prefixed with "dev_"). Also cuComplex is a CUDA data type found in the header "cucomplex.h" that comes with the toolkit, so there is no need to implement. I will try NSIGHT again, thanks. (not sure about downvote).

Comment: Various people consider a "works for me!" answer to be a poor one.  I was advised of such when I first started answering questions a few years ago.  It's a matter of opinion, of course, but it's a possible reason for the downvote.  It is generally accepted, however, that  questions asking for debugging help but failing to provide an MCVE should be voted for closure - this is explicitly stated on SO help pages.  Answering such questions, or attempting to do so, can also be considered bad form by some. Instead, encourage posting of an MCVE.

Comment: If you wish to perform the work you've done in your answer, one possible alternative approach is to add sufficient descriptive text in a comment to the question, suggesting an MCVE should be provided, and offering the code or fully-worked example in an external link such as pastebin.  If you peruse questions here you'll find examples of such behavior.  In any event, I don't wish to argue.  It's OK if we disagree.  It's the nature of community.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella for this explanation. The questions were: *Why is the kernel crashing for this larger matrix? Is there an out of bounds array access that I'm missing?*. What I tried to express in my answer was that the elements provided in the answer to not show any issue and the problem is somewhere else. Providing the functional code sample was to illustrate my saying. I don't know how to vote for close this question but I would got for it if proposed as danieljovan neither provided a MCVE nor marked that answer as valid. Thanks again Robert.

Comment: @danieljovan, 2896 lines is large. On some cards it may take a while. Have you checked your WDDM TDR statue ? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748979/varying-results-from-cublas/36752583#36752583 for an example.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, I posted a question on meta trying to understand better what a good answer is: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322045/how-to-disambiguate-a-question-between-a-fix-my-code-and-i-politely-believe-t . I did not explicitly cite your comment, but may if you think relevant.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET I didn't know about the WDDM TDR. According to my settings, the WDDM TDR delay is 2 and the WDDM TDR enabled field is set to True. I will set to False as per the recommendation on your post.

Comment: @danieljovan, depending on your configuration, you may want to start the NSIGHT Monitor as administrator for you setting change to be taken into account.

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET CUDA Debugging in NSIGHT just hangs indefinitely, even with the settings changed as above. Meanwhile I tried different data set sizes by altering the input data (in the text file). The maximum matrix size which works is 1569 x 1569; when I go up to 1570 x 1570, the kernel crashes. Any suggestions?

Comment: @danieljovan, I am out of ideas. I could not reproduce your issue. Did you get the full example I provided and run it on your system ?

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET I just solved the problem. You were right with respect to the TDR module. The kernel was hanging for a while. Even though I set the value to false, there was no change. Instead, I increased the TDR delay to 10 seconds. Turns out the kernel is running for 7 seconds (which I need to optimize now). Thank you for all your help. How can I close this question?