# "Object is owned by other context" error

Tags: opengl, nvidia, nsight

I am testing some OpenGL code.Using OpenGL 4.3.Nvidia GTX960M GPU.Windows10 64bit.Driver version:364.72

Trying to debug with NVidia NSight (version:4.7).The app is running fine untill I open NSight graphics debuggig.(Running GL debug output,zero errors).But when NSight is being launched I am getting this error:

> Source:OpenGL,type: Error, id: 1282, severity: High     Message:
>   GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. Object is owned by another
>   context and may not be bound here.

Then NSight debug windows is freezing and the app crashes on the close.

Before that, I had also CUDA code there with some OpenGL resources mapped to CUDA context.So I assumed that maybe some CUDA resource still holds OpenGL texture or buffer.I deleted everything,wrote from scratch only GL part.Not a line of CUDA.The error still persists.
The rendering is just simple quad with texture mapping.Can it be a bug in NSight?

Comment: You may want to verify the status of WDDM TDR flag in the NSIGHT monitor options as described briefly here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36752583/6218300 It might be that your GPU considers it is hanging for some reason, where it is just the debugger holding the process.

Comment: I am currently in touch with guys from NVidia.They say they experience issues with Nsight on laptops with Win10

Comment: Then, you may want to answer your own question explaining that there is some ongoing investigation at NVIDIA. This might save some SO contributor time.